# Header width 100% and has margins and I want it on full width (also applies on top)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

My header is not displaying with 100% width (entire width of the screen), instead it has margins: top, left, right and I did not tell it to have.

**CSS:**

```
div#header {
    background-color: #FF4800;
    float: top;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, `float: top` is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just need

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

By Default most browsers have margins set to html elements.

Try using a css reset http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: I don't know why but it did not happen before in Chrome.

Comment: can you share a link to the project?

Comment: I just started the website. Nothing much to share. It's the div and the css. Nothing interesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

div#header {
    background-color: #FF4800;
    height: 200px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Output on Safari:

[image: Output on Safari]